# Writing a variable into a cookie and subsequent reading in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Trying to store a variable into a cookie in JS and while trying to read the variable in the same run I get the previous value of the variable stored earlier.

```
<script>
...
setCookie('myVariable','1234',expiration);
</script>
```

```
<?php

print_r($_COOKIE['myVariable']);

?>
```

For example if in `myVariable` i have stored value '4321' previously, in the example code I don't see '1234' until the next refresh of the page but the old value of '4321'.

When is the cookie variable actually updated?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: You have to make a new call to PHP, such as submitting a form or reloading the page, to get the updated cookie.

Comment: First PHP generates the page and sends it to the browser, then browser executes your script setting a cookie. There's no cookie set at the first run.